# Inconsistent result when using a for loop in Python's callable function and doing it manually

Tags: python, python-2.x

I noticed an inconsistent behavior when using the `callable()` function, with the following code:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> for i in dir(x):
...    if '__' in i:
...        continue
...    else:
...        print i, callable(i)
```

I get the following results:

```
bit_length False
conjugate False
denominator False
imag False
numerator False
real False
```

But when manually using the `callable()` function:

```
>>> callable(x.bit_length)
True
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir(object)` [returns a list of strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), so what you're basically doing is `callable("bit_length")`, which is obviously false (strings aren't callable).

What you might want to do instead is something like:

```
for name in dir(obj):
    if "__" in name:
        continue
    attr = getattr(obj, name)
    print name, callable(attr)
```

Comment: Good explanation. The first code worked nicely for me. The second code, however, returned an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: As I said "if you were working with non-builtin types, you could do this". You are working with builtin types (int is a builtin type), so you can't use the second method.

Comment: I don't think the `__dict__` version of the code would work properly even for objects that do have a `__dict__`. On an instance, `__dict__` only holds the instance variables, not class variables like methods. To find them you'd need to look in `self.__class__.__dict__` and the `__dict__`s of all the base classes. And the values you get might not be what you want, as normal attribute lookups use the descriptor protocol (which is how `property` objects work, and how methods get bound to an instance).

Comment: @Blckknght Yeah, fair enough. I'll remove that example. I didn't really test the second example anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing whether the string named 'i' ('dir' returns a list of strings) is callable. The string is not callable. You need to get the atrribute from 'x' named 'i' and test that.